# Who is superior? Shiva or Vishnu or Brahma?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, puranas, brahma

**Vaishnavism** people claim that **Lord Vishnu** is Superior where as **Saivism** people claim that **Lord Shiva** is.

These people have proof of their **puranas** which backs-up their claims.

Is there any strong proof which can clear this doubt (obviously not **Purana**).

I read many scriptures regarding this doubt.All are giving me different opinions. Then I found out this website related to Hinduism. I have been reading answers here too but still it's not clear for me.

Everywhere I found some blind followers who do not even care to listen the complete question, get offended and said **their** lord is superior and gave rude opinions about others. They do not care for feeling of others.

Do their **lord** and their **purana** teaches them

-> To be rude to others who don't believe their **lords** is superior?

-> To insult others **lords**?

Comment: Yes. People are free to believe in their gods. No one can force them to change their belief. I too have found some of those(about whom you mentioned in your question). It's up to you to choose your path.

Comment: No purana or lord teaches to be rude or to insult. Only those idiot people who think themselves above God can do this. Best way is to ignore them and keep believing what you believe.

Comment: Even many people after reading vedas or purans (fake hinduism scholars) misunderstood the true meaning of **Lord** .

Comment: @Pritam: Thanks for your comments. But i am still looking for rock solid proof that can clear my doubt. Thanks again.

Comment: @MaitryShah Lord Vishnu is the supreme, even He is the creator of Brahma. You can find your answer form Vishnupuran, i dont have exact number of chapter and verse so i can't write this as answer but you can find it from latest hindu scripture Shreemad Bhagwadgeeta, whole Adhyay 10: Vibhutiyoga

Comment: @VipulHadiya: yes i know it. But is it same with shiva purana? Does Shiva purana says the same thing about lord vishnu?

Comment: @MaitryShah You didn't get my point. If Vishnu is creator of creator itself then He is the superior that i am trying to say. In short in debate if you say Brahma or Vishnu is superior then Vishnu then you can be easily defeated by others.

Comment: @Vipul Hadiya - There are instances in some puranas where Vishnu has prayed to Shiva. Also, Shiva Purana, Linga and Skandha purana describe greatness of Shiva, although there are instances in these puranas also where Vishnu is worshipped as Supreme. Given these variations how would you explain your stand?

Comment: Welcome to this site. Your inputs are very valuable. But for this specific question, could you please rephrase your question? As it is right now, it seems like you are asking 'Who is superior? Brahma or Vishnu or Shiva?' which is bound to spark off debates and will not lead to any solid conclusions as different sects believe different things. Such questions are usually discouraged on this site. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  This is clearly a core point of contention between the different sects of Hinduism, so it would lead to too much speculation and argument.  So I'm closing your question.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: You are the moderator. You can do what ever you want

Answer (score 2):

First you need to understand the concept that SHIVA, VISHNU AND BRAHMA are not human forms with four heads, six hands, snakes around neck and three eyed!
SHIVA,VISHNU, BRAHMA are MORPHOGENIC COSMIC FIELDS which produce enormous energy and vibration like magnetic and electric fields! Their forms are just depicted in human forms for easier understanding. For example: The third eye of shiva represents the awakening of pineal gland. The snakes around neck represents raised kundalini.

P.S. Avatars were the awakened beings who walked on this earth for real.

Comment: Can you please provide any reference  related to your answer? so that I can **understand** it.