# Who has created whom out of the following 3: Bramha, Vishnu, Shiva?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, brahma, creation

Who has created whom out of the following 3: Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva? I found conflicting texts in different books.

Comment: [possible duplicate] of [How were the Trimurthi born?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/237/2995)

Comment: That varies with Purana. Vishnu (Brahman for Vaishnavites) created Shankara(Just human form of Shiva;not Shiva) and Brahma. Similarly Shiva(Brahman for Shaivaites) created Narayana(may be lesser Vishnu) and Rudra ( Shankara, human form of Shiva). For Adavaitins, Shiva=Vishnu=Brahman. The three trinities are different attributes of Supreme Brahman. You can see this question http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8527/3500

Comment: @sv. The answers for that question are in Vaishnava perspective. Those might not answer his question. I think this question is  not possible duplicate for his question.

Comment: @AnilKumar, OP of the other question asks [But how were these gods born? Did the Supreme Lord (Brahman) make them?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/237/2995) which is essentially the same question as this. Feel free to answer the other question if you think the accepted answer doesn't cover everything :-) Also, we don't want to get into a war with questions like this: [Who is superior? Shiva or Vishnu or Brahma?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8193/2995)

Comment: @sv. No one can answer that question perfectly. Some believe Vishnu created other deities and some believe Shiva created other deities. Yeah,no one here wants to get into war. All i say is answer for that  linked question doesn't answer his question. Only Advaitin perspective can appease all.